# How can I find minimum and maximum value of date for ID 1 and 5 using python pandas?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

Here, as shown in image I want to find minimum and maximum value of date for ID 1 and 5. it is like for ID 1 minimum date is 2016-01-27 17:13:19
and maximum is 2016-03-28 00:56:43. Same for ID 5.

[Please Click to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9FBH.png)

Comment: there is no image. if you do not need an image, please copy/paste formatted data instead

Comment: I have shared link of image kindly check it. @GillesGouaillardet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregate,

Consider this df

```
    Date    ID
0   2016-3-28 00:56:43  1
1   2017-3-28 00:56:43  1
2   2005-3-28 00:56:43  1
3   2010-3-28 00:56:43  1
4   2002-3-28 00:56:43  1
5   2017-3-29 00:56:43  1
6   2004-3-28 00:56:43  5
7   2002-3-21 00:56:43  5
8   2015-3-28 00:56:43  5
9   2017-4-28 00:56:43  5
10  2009-3-28 00:56:43  5
11  2007-3-28 00:56:43  5
```

You can get min and max date for each id using

```
df.groupby('ID').Date.agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()
```

You get

```
    ID  min                 max
0   1   2002-3-28 00:56:43  2017-3-29 00:56:43
1   5   2002-3-21 00:56:43  2017-4-28 00:56:43
```

Comment: Glad that it worked, don't forget to accept/upvote the answer.